# What is the difference between "which is not to say" is "which doesn't mean"

Tags: differences

I've been wondering what is the difference.
Can the first one be generally replaced with the second one?
Plus, I believe "which is not to say" is more informal and used less frequently, is that correct?

Comment: If anyone thinks there's a difference (in meaning, or in "degree of informality), I suggest that's just a matter of opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so basically, completely interchangeable, in your view?

Comment: Where I'm from (Virginia, USA), "which is not to say" is sometimes used almost sarcastically, along the lines of "I'm not saying it, but I'm thinking it," and it is also used in the straightforward sense. I don't think "which doesn't mean" is used in the "sarcastic" sense. In the straightforward sense, I think they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say they are (can be) slightly different.

- *Which is not to say XYZ* **can** mean just that I do not want to say XYZ, without implying that it does not mean XYZ or without implying that I don't want to claim that it means XYZ.

  [Shades of the British version of *House of Cards*, where the protagonist says repeatedly, "You can say that. But I couldn't possibly comment." He in effect confirms that the thing is true (or he wants you to believe that it is), but he does so without saying it directly - in fact by denying that he is saying it.]
- *Which does not mean XYZ* is a solid affirmation that it does not mean XYZ.

I say "can mean" for the first because it depends on the context.

Comment: "I thoroughly disagree with you, which does not mean that events might not prove you right."  I don't call that a solid affirmation. "But that's not to say that many people might not agree with you."   (I'm not sure what I just said.)